# Div not width adapt to parent Angular Material

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

My form with #formLogin ID not adapt to width parent. It's small, it's weird.
Help me please.
I want to adapt the form to parent.
I see it very small.

```html
<body layout="row">
    <div flex>

    </div>
    <div id="formLogin" layout="column" layout-align="center center" flex="40" flex-sm="90" flex-md="70">
      <div>
        <md-toolbar class="md-primary">
          <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
            <h2 class="md-flex">Acceso a la Intranet</h2>
          </div>
        </md-toolbar>
        <md-content flex="auto" layout-padding>
          <md-input-container>
            <label>RUT</label>
            <input ng-model="login.rut" type="text">
          </md-input-container>
          <md-input-container>
            <label>Contraseña</label>
            <input ng-model="login.contrasena" type="password">
          </md-input-container>
          <md-button class="md-raised" style="width:90%;">Ingresar</md-button>
        </md-content>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div flex>

    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: How do you want it'll looks like? Do you wnat the Inputs to get strech?

Comment: I want to set 100% width the inputs to the flex parent

Answer (score 0):

By setting the attribute flex="grow" the element will fit its parent width and shrink automatically. Though you are also using layout-align="center center" which literally places the div vertically and horizontally in the center. I believe that's not exactly what you want, but if you read the documentation you'll get all your answers.

Comment: I try with the attribute flex="grow" but it doesn't work